# Complex calculation through c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone calculator app . I am facing problem in performing the multi operator calculation that is My display textbox has a value like this
200+350-420+1200-120-Sin(200)
how is calculation performed on "=" button click. I mean how will I identify and seperate operators from this string and calculate result?

Comment: No offence, but doesn't this question just boil down to "How do I write a calculator"?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you expect us to write your whole application for you?

Comment: See something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540864/calculator-issue

Comment: I have used this link to convert an expression like 2+3*(5+6) into its reverse polish notation equivalent, here is the link I used-http://yeolderealm.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/how-to-build-a-mathematical-formula-parser-in-c-%E2%80%93-implementing-complex-formula-values-in-your-rpg/ but how to calculate the result now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about expression evaluation. There is no need to reinvent the wheel, there are already many [components](http://flee.codeplex.com/) [available](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) [just](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3886/A-Math-Expression-Evaluator) [for](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7335/An-extensible-math-expression-parser-with-plug-ins) [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx) purpose.